# Hiding extensions using .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

What would be the correct method of using HTAccess to force .php to be hidden, including sub-folders. I've tried all of the other question answers.

Comment: Please show what you tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on

# remove php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# rewrite php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```